# SQL: Query two seperate tables and return counted values, then group by both returns

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I am struggling to get this query right. I have got the returned table to display nickname and the two associated values. The tables are:
Users(nickname, name etc)
postsAuth(nickname, postID etc)
postComm(nickname, comID etc)

I am trying to get it **NOT** to include the user if both values returned in numPosts & numComments are NULL (as in to say, if they haven't commented or created a post). I am unsure of how to get this to work. Code is as follows

```
SELECT u.nickname, pa.numPosts, pc.numComments
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pa.nickname, COUNT(pa.nickname) AS numPosts
    FROM postAuthors pa
    GROUP BY pa.nickname
)pa
ON u.nickname = pa.nickname LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT pc.nickname, COUNT(pc.nickname) AS numComments
    FROM postComments pc
    GROUP BY pc.nickname
)pc
ON u.nickname = pc.nickname;
```

this creates

```
Nickname | numPosts | numComments

bob              1             2
sally            2             1
tommy         NULL          NULL
 etc.......
```

I do not want `tommy` to be displayed.

Comment: Seems like you need INNER JOIN instead of LEFT one, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Please help to clarify 1. Is this either post or comments type requirement  2. Both required. In the later case filter the query by adding not null clause at the end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `WHERE pc.nickname IS NOT NULL OR pa.nickname IS NOT NULL` to the query i.e.

```
SELECT u.nickname, pa.numPosts, pc.numComments
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pa.nickname, COUNT(pa.nickname) AS numPosts
    FROM postAuthors pa
    GROUP BY pa.nickname
)pa
ON u.nickname = pa.nickname LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT pc.nickname, COUNT(pc.nickname) AS numComments
    FROM postComments pc
    GROUP BY pc.nickname
)pc
ON u.nickname = pc.nickname
WHERE pc.nickname IS NOT NULL OR pa.nickname IS NOT NULL
```

This will exclude any users who have no values in both postAuthors and postComments.

Comment: thanks i had tried WHERE and was getting syntax error. I must have written it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

use where clause and set not null condition

```
    SELECT u.nickname, tpa.numPosts, tpc.numComments
    FROM Users u
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT pa.nickname, COUNT(pa.nickname) AS numPosts
        FROM postAuthors pa
        GROUP BY pa.nickname
    )tpa
    ON u.nickname = tpa.nickname LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT pc.nickname, COUNT(pc.nickname) AS numComments
        FROM postComments pc
        GROUP BY pc.nickname
    )tpc
    ON u.nickname = tpc.nickname;
   where tpa.nickname is not null or tpc.nickname is not null
```

Comment: AND takes all the null out, need to be OR. Other than that this works. I had tried where several times and was getting syntax error

Comment: @Malkeir i think you didn't  use alias thats why you got sytax error

Comment: honestly unsure how mine was different. I may have written NOT NULL and not IS NOT NULL. but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can control it while you are showing in the page by this condition.

```
if(object->property_name==Null && object->property_name==Null ){
 continue;
}
```